# Equivalent of Clearcase streams in Perforce

Tags: perforce, clearcase

I come from Clearcase world and am trying to learn Perforce at my new company

Clearcase has a concept of streams (which is different than a branch).  Likewise Perforce also has a  concept of Streams.

The Question
Is the perforce stream same as Clearcase stream.

Thanks
Pedro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Perforce Streams](http://www.perforce.com/product/product_features/perforce_streams) follows the same logic than ClearCase UCM Streams, in that they:

- Model the flow of change
- Provide Fast context switching and in-place branching
- Manage stream composition and dependencies

You do find the same notion of parent/children stream hierachy (see [p4 stream](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/stream.html)).

The main difference is in its content:

- P4 Stream contents are defined by the paths that you map (so you can map any path you want)
- UCM Streams are defined by the baselines of the components (which are fixed paths, one for each component: you cannot specify *any* path)

And through the new [*virtual* Streams](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120130/new-20121-virtual-streams) (2012.1 version of Perforce), they even allows you to visualize a subset of configuration  (filtered view): that isn't present in UCM streams.